# Sequence of Contractive Maps Converges?

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose I have a sequence of contractive maps with contraction constants $(1-a_i)$, where $0 < a_i < 1$. If the sum of the $a_i$ diverges, how can I show that the sequence $x_{i+1} = f_i(x_i)$ converges? Assume we are in a compact complete metric space.

Comment: In $\mathbb R$, we can let $f_k(x)=k+\frac12x$, so all $a_k$ are $=\frac12$. The sequence with $x_0=0$ does not converge for we have $x_n\ge n$.

Comment: Interesting counter example. I got this exercise from "Fractal Based Methods in Analysis" and the authors seem to think the sequence should converge. I must be missing something?

Comment: Is it possible the metric space is supposed to be compact?

Comment: This is not stated explicitly in the exercise, but that must be what the authors intended I guess.

Comment: I have edited my post to ask the question for a compact space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The principal trick suggested by these assumptions is that
$$
\prod_{i=1}^\infty(1-a_i)\le e^{-\sum_{i=1}^\infty a_i}
$$
converges to zero.

---

You can combine sufficient numbers of maps $f_i$ so that their concatenation $g_j$ has a contraction constant smaller some pre-selected $\varepsilon>0$. I.e., without loss of generality one can assume that $a_i\ge 1-ε$.

Now each map $f_i$ has a fixed point $z_i$ and if $R$ is the radius of the compact $X$, then the image of $f_i$ is contained in $B(z_i,2εR)$. Assume $ε$ is so small that even $2εR$ is very small. Then the sequence $x_i$ will jump from close to $z_i$ to close to $z_{i+1}$. While there must be limit points of the sequence, there does not need to be convergence.

---

Example: On $X=[0,1]$ alternate the maps $f_{2m}(x)=εx$ and $f_{2m+1}(x)=1-εx$. $f_1(f_0(x))=1-ε^2x$ has the fixed point $1/(1+ε^2)$, $f_0(f_1(x))= ε-ε^2x$ has the fixed point $ε/(1+ε^2)$, $a_0=a_1=1-ε$, so the series of the $a_i$ diverges.

---

Thinking about it again, there was a reason this seemed familiar. This setup readily applies to the situation of a chaos game for the construction resp. approximation of an IFS fractal. There you generate a random sequence out of a set of contrative maps and get a sequence of points that accumulates to give the shape of Julia sets, Barnsley ferns or Sierpinski triangles.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks. I am aware of that the product you mentioned converges to 0. Looking for more details in the solution.

Comment: Interesting! Seems I have a bone to pick with the authors of my book!

Comment: Yes, particularly since chaos games to generate pictures of IFS fractals were once almost as popular as the Mandelbrot set.

Comment: I have not gotten to the chaos game in my book yet, but I will keep this in mind. thanks!